# EF Core tools - wrong error message when migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard

I have two projects 
1. Swps.Scheme.Webjob - .netCore 3.0 
2. Swps.Scheme.Domain - .NetStandard 2.1  , the scheme.domain has my dbContext and I am trying to do a add-migation

when do a add-migration in PMC, I am getting this error from the console

> "Project 'Domain Scheme\Server\Swps.Scheme.Webjob' targets framework
>   **'.NETStandard'**. The Entity Framework Package Manager Console Tools don't support this framework."

The error itself is wrong, the project which is .netCore, the console identifies as NETStandard. Can you please help "

[image]

Comment: You probably have to wrong project set as your startup.

Comment: Resolved - EntityFrameworkCore\add-migration works. I had both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 were installed.